Generic type that acts like base type
I want to create a generic type A[T] that acts exactly like T, except that I can tell at runtime that the type is in fact A[T] and not T.
I tried
class A(Generic[T], T):
    pass

but that does not seem to work, as mypy complains, for example, that A[str] is of type object.
As an example, I want something like this to pass type checking:
def f(s: A[str]):
    return re.findall('foo|bar', s)

But still be somehow able to tell A[str] from str at runtime, when I get a variable of that type or inspect the function signature.
Is there a way to do this?

One way is to use a generic type alias that returns its only type argument:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
type A[T] = T

def f(s: A[str]) -> None:
    reveal_type(s)            # str
    re.findall('foo|bar', s)  # fine

f('')   # fine

>>> type(inspect.get_annotations(f)['s'])
<class 'types.GenericAlias'>

In older Python versions, use typing_extensions.TypeAliasType:
from typing import TypeVar
from typing_extensions import TypeAliasType

T = TypeVar('T')
A = TypeAliasType('A', T, type_params = (T,))
#                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This part is optional

Another way is to use Annotated[]:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
from typing import Annotated

# There must be at least two arguments
def f(s: Annotated[str, 'Whatever']) -> None:
    reveal_type(s)            # str
    re.findall('foo|bar', s)  # fine

f('')   # fine

>>> type(inspect.get_annotations(f)['s'])
<class 'typing._AnnotatedAlias'>

The latter is preferred, especially if you want to attach metadata to the type in question.

Thank you! Any way to do this in Python 3.9?

@Knoep See the linked Mypy playgrounds; type A[T] = T is just 3.12+ syntax for A: TypeAlias = T, with TypeAlias imported from typing_extensions for 3.9 and older.

Unfortunately, I'm getting TypeError: 'TypeVar' object is not subscriptable on the function definition if I run the version with TypeAlias in python (mypy is happy).

@Knoep Right, I forgot that. Use A = TypeAliasType('A', T) then.

Perfect, that works! Maybe you can add it to the answer?

Updated the answer accordingly.
